# Implement Security to this application?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, security

At the moment I am attempting to create an application that passes on data to delete a row in my database. This row will be known by the ID passed on by the html file to js.

Currently I have a Html file, Javascript and PHP file which all work together to get this data passed in.

What im looking to do is secure it so no-one unauthorised can just send data to the javascript document in-order to delete the row.

HTML -- > JS --> PHP

JS:

```
    function deleteListing(id) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")
    if (answer) {
        $.post("assets/scripts/deleteListing.php", {
            id: id
        },

        function (result) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (response.available === true) {
                location.reload();
            } else if (response.available === false) {
           //     alert("FAILURE DELETING USER");
            } else if (response.root === true) {
            //    alert("Cannot Delete Root User..");
            }
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
 <?
    require("../../../assets/config/config.php");
    $id_retrieve = $_POST['id'];
    $data = new stdClass();
    $sth= $dbh-> prepare("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id='".$id_retrieve."'");
    $sth -> execute();
    $row = $sth -> fetch();
    $data->available = true;
    $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = '".$id_retrieve."'");
    echo json_encode($data);     
?>
```

Before anyone says the statement is not created using the prepared statement, I am aware of this and will fix it asap. Apart from that, is there anyway I can secure the Javascript file from unauthorised access? or could I limit it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not check the authorization in your backend? You could use sessions.

Comment: also, you should use parametrize query with prepare not injecting `$id_retrieve` directly

Comment: Is the HTML file secured in any way? Or is it HTML generated from a PHP file that includes authentication & authorisation?

Comment: the only real security must be implemented server side, on the client side, everything is insecure (i can send any http header i want, with or without javascript). any security check in javascript would be only for usability

Comment: The HTML file is secured with a session yes, but is that enough? What are the other alternatives?

Comment: @OliverK You need to use that same security on your deleteListing.php then. *Anything* else is open to compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions.

As @Tobias said above: Use sessions to handle the authentication.  That will protect you some.

However, that alone doesn't stop Cross-Session attacks.

Take a look at this page: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html

It suggests putting a token value on the form *and* saving it in the session.  That way, when the form is submitted you can compare the incoming token against the one in your session and verify that the form did, indeed, come from your site.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

        $fp = fopen('./messages.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "$message<br />");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="message"><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

readfile('./messages.txt');

?>
```

Comment: Started to think further about this, what if a hacker decided to hijack the token session and then use the same token as a post request?

Comment: How can they hijack the token?

Comment: Assuming they made their own, For example, i created my own html page, made it generate its own token, created a session for that token, and then posted the token to the php page.

Comment: A another user (or hacker) would have their own unique session with unique session variables and token.  You don't assign the token until after the user has logged in. (Access control isn't shown in this code example.)